# Error during insert BLOB data in oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have 2 schema in same database with same table name and structure

In schema_1 BLOB table inserting records live data. I created another schema_2 and created same table name and structure of schema_1.

Now when I try to insert records from schema_1 to schema_2 table then I am getting following error

```
ORA-01555: snapshot too old: rollback segment number  with name "" too small
ORA-22924: snapshot too old
```

Insert Query of schema_2:

```
insert into blob_table
(id, blob_col)
select id, blob_col from tab_schema_1
where blob_col is not null;
```

Oracle Database 11G 64bit with DB BLOCK SIZE 32768

How to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Here is a question on DBA stackexchange you may find useful: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/146592/ora-01555-snapshot-too-old-rollback-segment-with-name-too-small-error

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need 
insert into schema2.blob_table
(id, blob_col)
select id, blob_col from schema1.tab_schema_1
where schema1.blob_col is not null;

Answer (score 0):

If in Automatic Undo Management mode, increase the setting of UNDO_RETENTION. Otherwise, use larger rollback segments.

[https://taliphakanozturken.wordpress.com/2018/09/12/how-to-optimize-oracle-undo-parameters/][1]

undo retention time=(undo size)/(db block size × undo block per second)

```
SQL>ALTER SYSTEM SET UNDO_RETENTION = 1000 TO 2400; --1000 and 2400 are examples
```